# Display view above status bar?

Tags: android, eclipse, view, statusbar

I recently saw an image of an app that was capable of displaying a view above the status bar and was also able to cover it with a view.

I know you can get a view right below the status bar from a view with align parent top. But how would you get a view on top of the status bar??

[Example](http://tombarrasso.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ChargeBarBanner3-225x225.png)

Comment: any link to the image to figure out what you are talking about?

Comment: Are you talking about https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tombarrasso.android.wp7barfree

Comment: Thats right. Click the example to see an example of the image. anyways, i did not kno you could even do that. I thought the status bar was above all and it could only be hidden if you want

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer by @Sadeshkumar is incorrect for ICS and above (perhaps GB as well).

A view created with `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and `FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN` is covered by the `StatusBar`.

To get an overlay on top of the `StatusBar`, you need to use `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` instead of `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`.

The problem being then, how to get clicks/touches?

Comment: Is there w way to get the touch events using system overlay?

Answer (score 29):

### **Disable the System Status Bar - Without Root**

---

After two full days of searching through SO posts and reading the Android docs over and over.. Here is the solution that I came up with. (tested)

```
    mView= new TextView(this);                                       
    mView.setText(".........................................................................");                       

    mLP = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            100,
            // Allows the view to be on top of the StatusBar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            // Keeps the button presses from going to the background window
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            // Enables the notification to recieve touch events
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            // Draws over status bar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    mLP.gravity =  Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER;      

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLP);
```

Dont forget the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW" />
```

Note:
 Tested upto kitkat.

Comment: WindowManager shoud be taken like this getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

Comment: Need this permission tooo   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

Answer (score 6):

A view created with `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` and `FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN` is covered by the `StatusBar`.

Comment: and TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR + FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN will be touchable.

Answer (score 4):

```
 int statusBarHeight = (int) Math.ceil(25 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);


  View statusBarView = new View(MyActivity.this);
  statusBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);


  WindowManager.LayoutParams params = null;
  params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,statusBarHeight,WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(statusBarView, params);
```