# How to show Application Icon and Text on top left corner at Home screen in android

Tags: android, android-screen, home-screen-widget

I want to show my AppIcon and some text on Top Left Corner at Home Screen. Please look at the picture you will get an idea

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: simply  generate notification when you launched app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to create an "Ongoing" notification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693997/android-how-to-create-an-ongoing-notification)

Comment: Check this: [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar its working good, app icon is showing but text is not showing?

Comment: I don't think its possible to show a notification in the statusbar with text.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar Yes it is showing for first time but after that it disappear is there not a method to show text permanently as like app icon?

Comment: no there is no other way to show text permanent because its for get user attention that app is running and using something. text is only showing when you drag notification penal.

Comment: @PirFahimShah you are taking about text "SpyVideo Enable"??

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar yup about that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for R.Video enable you are already using ongoing notification.

---

for `SpyVideo Enable` text showing at bottom centre of screen. you can use chat head like Facebook! download this [samplecode](https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead). instead of ImageView you have to use TextView.

Comment: yes, but i need to show the text with app icon like in OnGoingNotification, is it not possible in OnGoingNotification

Comment: Can you help me in recording video in background and when i click on the app then video recording stop, and video save in gallery path? plz

Comment: @PirFahimShah: check this answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/14952081/1168654 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/16552892/1168654 and http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/845710/Android-Record-video-in-background-and-simultaneou

Comment: you are really a star. Glad to help you in brightness your future, Once again Thanks

Comment: you have to fix some error in different android version http://stackoverflow.com/q/26305107/1168654

Comment: i solved it, i am releasing the camera parameter if it is not null, now its working. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might use drawing over apps.
Here a link: [How to draw a view on top of everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264650/android-how-to-draw-view-over-top-of-everything)

Maybe that helps.

Comment: what exactly this code do, is it showing app icon and text on home screen top?

Comment: This code draws over the whole home screen. You can put a view on top of the statusbar. Its similar to what Facebook messenger is doing.

Comment: this link might be a better example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815901/display-view-above-status-bar